# Can Same Command(button) part of toolbar and menu bar is vsct file(visual studio extension)

Tags: vsct

I am trying to create visual studio extension (converting vs add-in), I need to place all the toolbar buttons as part of menu(as submenu of menu item under tools menu) also. is it possible to have toolbar command in menu.

I am trying to avoid recreating the same buttons.